# How to remove id location strategy from Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide, zk

the problem is: my web application uses ZK, which automatically generates random UUID for each web element.

When I try to record some basic test-case with Selenium IDE, it automatically tries to use these randomly-generated ID's, without even giving me a good alternative.

### Is there a way to forbid Selenium IDE to use IDs while locating elements?

Possible workaraounds:

1. Implement ID generator in ZK: I've thrown away this possibility, because the application GUI is too complex for this task, and ID should be unique for whole sesion, which make this workaraound really hard to implement, when you have same elements on different page.
2. Find another recording tool: I've only found XLT script developer, which does the work by writing DOM-path using classes (which zk gives plenty) - but sometimes the location strategy gives false path, which is then not reproducible. Any good alternatives here?

Answer (score 0):

You can change locater builder by changing the order of the locater in options>locater builder.
For example if you want to give first preference to css: name drag it on the top so when you start recording it will first give the preference to css name

Hope this will help you